# R- How to return named list without printing to console

Tags: r

I want to return a named list from a function, f. 
For example, calling f(args) gives me a named list of variables named x and y.
I use return(list(x=x,y=y)) at the end of my function.

```
$x
[1] 1 2

$y
[1] 12
```

The problem is that the output above always prints  the values of entire list to the console. I want to avoid this because $x may take the value of a very large matrix. Is there a way for me to define model<-f(args) and surpress the print out of the $x values when I type model into the console. Instead, I just want to access x by model$x.

Comment: Just assign it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `invisible`:

```
f <- function(x, y) {
    invisible(list(x, y))
}

f(rnorm(1e4), rnorm(1e4))
## (nothing)

str(f(rnorm(1e4), rnorm(1e4)))
# List of 2
#  $ : num [1:10000] 2.402 0.51 -1.117 0.415 0.849 ...
#  $ : num [1:10000] -0.642 0.967 -0.328 -0.33 -0.914 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I am in a search for a similar solution. Just like the comment above, a way of avoiding output in the console, is to assign the output of a function that returns a list, to a variable. I do understand that this may not be the solution for all cases however.

```
f<-function(x=1,y=1){
   return(list(x=x,y=y))
}

result<-f()
```